# SQL date issue when date is not isdate

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Expiry                             DateEnd

None                        2000-06-29 00:00:00.000

None                        2000-06-29 00:00:00.000

september 2013              2013-06-29 00:00:00.000

January 2012                2013-06-29 00:00:00.000

May 2020                    2013-06-29 00:00:00.000

2013-06-29 00:00:00.000     2013-06-29 00:00:00.000
```

From two column I want pick all dates except May 2020 rows, due to future date.
this is what I have so far

```
DECLARE @YearFlag datetime

SET @YearFlag = DATEADD(yy,-5,GETDATE())

SELECT * 
FROM #Table
WHERE (DateEnd IS NULL OR DateEnd = '' OR DateEnd <= @YearFlag)
   OR (CHARINDEX(Convert(varchar, YEAR(GETDATE())),Expiry) > 0)
```

was using below one to pick January 2012 row but getting error

```
OR (Expiry != 'none' AND Expiry  <= GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to exclude future dates from your select, so you can use something like this.

(also, please specify RDBMS because the GETDATE() function might not be available in the one you're using)

```
SELECT Expiry,
    DateEnd
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE Expiry <> 'none'
      AND convert(INT, substring(expiry, charindex(' ', expiry, 0), len(expiry))) < YEAR(GETDATE())
      AND CASE LOWER(substring(expiry, 0, charindex(' ', expiry, 0)))
          WHEN 'january' THEN 1
          WHEN 'february' THEN 2
          WHEN 'march' THEN 3
          WHEN 'april' THEN 4
          WHEN 'may' THEN 5
          WHEN 'june' THEN 6
          WHEN 'july' THEN 7
          WHEN 'august' THEN 8
          WHEN 'september' THEN 9
          WHEN 'october' THEN 10
          WHEN 'november' THEN 11
          ELSE 12
          END < MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f643/3) with how the code works.

Comment: first filter kills it

Comment: @MeteAgar Ok, I understand now what you mean.

Comment: @MeteAgar You can use this (althought it's not yeat complete, I have to add the month condition). Currently it's only comparing the year.

Comment: @MeteAgar You're done. Here's the code. You might want to add other conditions you want, I haven't added all of them, I just fixed the issue you were having.